# Triangular Slider to share 100 percent into three parts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, math, geometry

Problem is the following:

I've got this triangle and every edge of this represents one value, all values together should be 100% (every time!).

The calculation while moving the red dot seems to work quite well, but the initial positioning is totally messed up, math-class is quite long ago and so i think, after hours of try and error, i need some help.

I think the fiddle is quite self-explaining.

```
>> http://jsfiddle.net/ub1bgrfr/
```

Comment: Don't know the answer but it was fun to play with for a couple of minutes. Noticed the numbers don't always add to 100 though - as you move along the bottom it goes from 4/86/10 to 4/86/12 then to 4/84/12

Comment: You're essentially dealing with barycentric coordinates, so see [Wikipedia on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Conversion_between_barycentric_and_Cartesian_coordinates).